# Finding the CDF of a given PDF

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

$$f(x)=(1/2)e^{-|x|}$$
How should I go about solving this problem? I need to find the CDF of the given PDF. The absolute value is throwing me for a loop.

Answer (score 3):

$F(x) = \begin{cases} \int_{-\infty}^x \frac 12 e^x dx &x\le0\\ \int_{-\infty}^0 \frac 12 e^x dx+ \int_{0}^x \frac 12 e^{-x} dx  &x>0 \end{cases}$